# Add item to object if the object exists or create new object if it does not exists

Tags: javascript, object

I need to add an item to an object if the object exists, otherwise I need to create new object with the item.
I know the existence of `Object.assign` function, but I am not sure how to use it.

Right now this is what I tried:

```
var myvar = obj ? Object.assign(obj, { "myvar" : "myvalue" }) : { "myvar" : "myvalue" };
```

Is this the right and the cleaner way to do that?

Comment: you can simply use `Object.assign({},obj, { "myvar" : "myvalue" })`, no need of ternary.

Comment: @AZ_ it works and it seems cleaner than mine solution. thanks

Comment: @AZ_ I get a reference error if obj isn't defined (using Firefox).

Comment: @Frazer you must define the variables first.

Answer (score 2):

copy/pasted from one of my owns projects

Personnaly, I always do that :

```
var forms = forms || {};

forms.state = forms.state || {};
```

first line : if 'forms' was previously undefined or null, it will create a new object. Otherwise, forms will be assigned to its previous value. (I use that a lot when I have applications with simple JS or Jquery only), it allows me to kind of namespace my application without caring about file loading order.

The second line checks if the object 'state' already exists. If it already exists, it assigns 'forms.state' to 'forms.state'. Otherwise, it creates a new object.

Comment: I do not understand this code. I need to add new item to the object if the object does exist

Comment: @GiacomoM I added a few details, tell me if it suits you

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
(obj||{})["myvar"] = "myvalue"
```

```js
obj = { test: 'ok' };

var myvar = (obj||{})["myvar"] = "myvalue";

console.log(myvar);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Surely smaller than mine

Answer (score 1):

Can use the object spread operator.

```
var myvar = { ...obj, "myvar": "myvalue"}
```

Answer (score -1):

Test if the object is defined.

```js
let obj = null;

if (typeof obj === "undefined") obj = {};
let updatedObj = Object.assign({},obj, {"myVar": "my value"});

console.log(updatedObj);

// or in one line
let obj2 = null;

let updatedObj2 = (typeof obj2 === "undefined")? {"myVar": "my value"} : Object.assign({},obj2, {"myVar": "my value"});

console.log(updatedObj2);
```

**Edit**: In case `obj` is `null`

Comment: what if  `obj` is defined but not initialized?

Comment: `typeof obj === "undefined"` will be `true` Or I'm missing something.

Comment: It will be `undefined` but the check is more suitable for `not defined` variables. Also, your code will fail for `obj = null`